# Can't make mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql

If I use the following code, it works:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

But when I do this, it doesn't:

```
$db_host='localhost';
$db_id='root';
$db_pass='';
$con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_id, $db_pass);

if (!$con)  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Trying to swap (") and (').

Comment: Your code looks valid. Please edit the question with the details on the error output. Also, try to cast: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` right after the `<?php` or `<?` code open tag. Obviously, after a space ;)

Comment: "Doesn't work". Great. You'll have to fix it, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_ functions are discouraged for new applicationa you are advised to use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The following code uses PDO to connect to database.

```
//dependant on your setup
$host= "localhost";
$username="XXX";
$password="YYY";
$database="ZZZ";

// connect to the database  
try {  
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
    //Remainder of code
  }  

catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]'). $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);//Change file name to suit  
}  
// close the connection
$dbh = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a script like this

```
$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_id = 'root'; 
$db_pass ='';
$con = mysql_connect ($ db_host, $ db_id, $db_pass) or die ('Could not connect:'. mysql_error ());
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this?

Answer (score 0):

That code is fine.   Review the error log- the problem has to be external to that code.